# Why Linux does not crash but output an random string?

Tags: c, linux, crash

```
char* getChar()
{
    //char* pStr = "TEST!!!";
    char str[10] = "TEST!!!";
    return str;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double *XX[2];

    printf("STR is %s.\n", getChar());
    return (0);
}
```

I know a temporary variable in a stack SHOULD not be returned.

Actually it will output a undecided string.

When does Linux crash except NULL-Pointer-Reference?

Comment: I dislike the `getChar` name, too similat to standard `getchar`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: *That's* what you don't like about this code?!?

Comment: Not only, since I also answered!

Comment: *I know a temporary variable in a stack SHOULD not be returned.* Seems like you already know the answer.

Comment: Linux is not crashing, it is just your process which is terminated.

Answer (score 5):

You've got some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) to have an idea of what that could mean.

If you wish an explanation, you need to dive into implementation specific details.
Here it goes....

This `carp.c` file (very similar to yours, I renamed `getChar` to `carp` and included `<stdio.h>`)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 char *carp() {
   char str[10] = "TEST!!!";
   return str;
 }
 int main(int argc, char**argv)
 {
   printf("STR is %s.\n", carp());
   return 0;
 }
```

is compiled by `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S carp.c` into a good warning

```
carp.c: In function 'carp':
carp.c:4:8: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
      return str;
      ^
```

and into this assembler code (GCC 4.9.1 on Debian/Sid/x86-64)

```
    .text
.Ltext0:
        .globl  carp
        .type   carp, @function
carp:
.LFB11:
        .file 1 "carp.c"
        .loc 1 2 0
        .cfi_startproc
        .loc 1 5 0
        leaq    -16(%rsp), %rax #, tmp85
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
        .size   carp, .-carp
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "STR is %s.\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB12:
        .loc 1 7 0
        .cfi_startproc
.LVL0:
        subq    $24, %rsp       #,
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
        .loc 1 8 0
        movq    %rsp, %rsi      #,
.LVL1:
        movl    $.LC0, %edi     #,
.LVL2:
        movl    $0, %eax        #,
        call    printf  #
.LVL3:
        .loc 1 10 0
        movl    $0, %eax        #,
        addq    $24, %rsp       #,
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE12:
        .size   main, .-main
```

As you notice, the bad `carp` function is returning the stack pointer minus 16 bytes. And `main` would print what happens to be there. And what happens to be at that location probably depends upon a lot of factors (your environment [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), the [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) used for the stack, etc....). If you are interested in understanding what exactly is the memory (and address space) at entry into `main`, dive into [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), your compiler's [crt0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0), your kernel's source code, your dynamic linker source code, your `libc` source code, the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf),  etc.... My life is too short to take many hours to explain all of this.

BTW, notice that the initialization of local `str` to `"TEST!!!"` has been *rightly* [optimized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) out by my compiler.

Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html): your process can be terminated in many cases (I won't call that "Linux crashing" like you do), e.g. when dereferencing a pointer out of its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26444959)), executing a bad machine code, etc...

Comment: Your explanation is amazing.
-------
Generally when does Linux crash except NULL-Pointer-Reference?

Answer (score 2):

It didn't crash because you got lucky; since you have no way of knowing just how long this string that gets printed is, you have no idea what parts of memory it will venture into.